# Codeception 'Undefined variable output' when trying to run a unit test

Tags: php, codeception

When attempting to run a simple unit test, as follows

```
// tests
public function testMe()
{
    $this->assertEquals(1+1, 2);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: output in phar://C:/bin/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Lib/Parser.php on line 129
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\bin\codecept.phar:0
PHP   2. require_once() C:\bin\codecept.phar:7
PHP   3. Codeception\Application->run() phar://C:/bin/codecept.phar/codecept:36
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() phar://C:/bin/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Application.php:103
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() phar://C:/bin/codecept.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() phar://C:/bin/codecept.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:186
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() phar://C:/bin/codecept.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:815
PHP   8. Codeception\Command\Run->execute() phar://C:/bin/codecept.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
PHP   9. Codeception\Command\Run->runSuites() phar://C:/bin/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php:256
PHP  10. Codeception\Codecept->run() phar://C:/bin/codecept.phar/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php:329
```

The line in question, 129 in `Parser.php`is the following:

```
public static function validate($file)
{
    $config = Configuration::config();
    if (empty($config['settings']['lint'])) { // lint disabled in config
        return;
    }
    exec("php -l ".escapeshellarg($file)." 2>&1", $output, $code);
    if ($code !== 0) {
        throw new TestParseException($file, implode("\n", $output));
    }
}
```

The line 129 is `exec("php -l ".escapeshellarg($file)." 2>&1", $output, $code);`

I have tried googling around, and couldn't find any one else with the issue. This is in a completely "empty" php project, with only this unit test. I installed Codeception with composer.

I created the test as follows:

`codecept generate:test unit Example`

filled in the above and

`codecept run unit`

Codeception version: 2.2.2

Php version: 5.6.21

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found more information, namely here:

https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3324

It seems that this is a very new problem with version "2.2.*"

The possible solutions are:

## Disable linting

Insert

```
settings:
    lint: false
```

Into the `codeception.yaml` file.

## Downgrade

Since validation is introduced in version 2.2, downgrading to the latest version (2.1.11) should also fix the issue according to the devs.